# How to make git log output not printed to screen

Tags: linux, git

When I use 'git log', and then type 'q', I still see the logs on my screen as like it was printed to the screen.

I want to do it like in vim, when I open a file in vim and then close it I don't see file content, I see only the vim command.
How to let git log not showing the log after exiting? (like in less command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use less utility, it would look like:

```
$ git log | less
```

Comment: @AtheelMassalha to make it permanent you can use shell alias `alias git-log-no-rubbish='git log | less'`, and put it into ~/.bashrc file

Comment: @AtheelMassalha it's only alias to 'git log | less'. Check this : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/ . After that you can type in shell `git-log-no-rubbish` and it will do the same as `git log | less`

Comment: nice, now I see it works
I will mark this as correct answer but I bielve there is a way to get the same with "git log" and not with another aliased name
thanks for the help!

Comment: More likely, you just need to do `PAGER=less`.  What is happening is that `git-log` is piping its output through `PAGER` and you are just explicitly overriding that behavior by piping explicitly to `less`.  Also note that all of these will fail (ie, work properly) if you have included `X` in `LESS`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell PAGER=less didn't change git log behave, should I do it with another commands?
and what do you mean by including X in less?

Comment: You need `export PAGER=less` (also, check that GIT_PAGER is empty).  If you also have `export LESS=X`, then `less` will run as if `-X` was passed on the command line, giving you the behavior you are trying to avoid.

Comment: thanks, those helped me:
export LESS=R
git config --global --add core.pager "less -F"
but its only working for git diff/log, if I do 'git show HEAD' it still prints to the screen. is there any global fix for all git commands?